# Temporarily storing data in record to reduce query redundancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The example below shows redundancy as the database is queried twice for exactly the same thing.

```
.div1
    - towns.each do |town|
        = town.name
        - town.residents.where(:age => 14).each do |r|
            %p= r.name

.div2
    - towns.each do |town|
        = town.name
        - town.residents.where(:age => 14).each do |r|
            %p= r.name
```

Is there anyway I can simplify this?

Comment: Is this really queried twice? Rails should cache the result!? What db and Rails version are you using? Can you provide the output of the server?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Would rails cache this result? I wasn't aware. I am using rails 4.2

Comment: @sawa it's `haml` a markup language for Rails

Comment: The sample language is haml. The framework is ruby on rails. @sawa

Comment: Tag for it, or write that in the question.

Comment: @sawa I don' t think this a `haml` question. As me and other commented Rails should cache the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Rails should cache the query. It is not fired twice to the database.

Comment: This is true. Why not it is posted as a comment? :D

Comment: @JeremyRichards if you see something witch `CACHED` in your Rails server logs the query should not be sent twice. But the best way may be the answer of @mgidea if you don't use the `@towns` anywhere in the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can optimize the queries by including or preloading the relations object.

```
towns = towns.preload(:residents)
```

this will select the residents records of the towns ahead of time

if you are only looking for the towns with residents that are age 14 then

```
towns = towns.joins(:residents).preload(:residents).where(:residents => {:age => 14}).uniq
```